# Change saved tensorflow model input shape at inference time

Tags: tensorflow, input, tensorflow2.0, shapes

I've searched everywhere but couldn't find anything. It looks so weird that nobody have already encountered the same problem as I... Let me explain:

I've trained a **Tensorflow 2** custom model. During the training I have used `set_shape((None, 320, 320, 14))` so that Tensorflow knows the shape (It couldn't infer it for whatever reason... -_-").
I have also saved my **custom model** at every 100 epochs using:

```py
model.save(os.path.join('models', 'pb', FLAGS.task_name + '-%i' % epoch))
```

So for the 100th epoch I will have a folder `models/pb/my_name-100` that contains

- assets
- variables
- saved_model.pb

Now, at inference time, I just want to load the model (without all the code). So I have created another piece of code that only loads the model and make a prediction... A basic template looks like:

```py
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model)

    def predict(self, input_tensor):
        pred = self.model(input_tensor[None, ...])
        return pred[0]
```

Where `input_tensor` is of size (H, W, 14) and so `input_tensor[None, ...]`  is of size:
(None, H, W, 14).

The problem is that, because I have set the shape during training to be (None, 320, 320, 14)... This stupid Tensorflow expects the input to be (None, 320, 320, 14) -_-"!!!. My Neural Network is a fully convolutional neural network, so I really don't care about the input shape. I set it to be (320, 320, 14) during training for memory reason...

During prediction I'd like to be able to do prediction on any kind of shape.

Obviously, I could do a preprocessing function that extracts patch of size (320, 320) from the input image and tiles them. So for example my `input_tensor` could be of size (30, 320, 320, 14)

And then after the prediction, I could reconstruct the image from the tiles... But I don't want to do that.

- **Firstly** because It takes a bit of time to create the tiles and reconstruct the image from the tile
- **Secondly** because the result will be a bit off due to 0 padding in the convolution. Which means that I need to create overlapping tiles and average the results on the overlapping part to avoid having artifacts during the reconstruction

So my question is simple:
How can I tell tensorflow to accept any width and height at inference time? Omg it's so bothersome. I can't believe that there are not an easy options available to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question.
Unfortunately, my answer **will not satisfy** everybody. There are so many convoluted things happening in TF (Not to mention that when you search for help, most of it concern the 1st API... -_-").

Anyway, here is the "solution"

In my Neural Network, I have implemented a **custom layer** to mimic the pytorch function [AdaptiveAvgPool2D](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d.html). My implementation actually use `tf.nn_avg_pool` under the hood and need to dynamically compute the **kernel_size** as well as the **stride**. Here is my code, for reference:

```py
class AdaptiveAvgPool2d(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_shape, data_format='channels_last'):
        super(AdaptiveAvgPool2d, self).__init__(autocast=False)
        assert data_format in {'channels_last', 'channels_first'}, \
            'data format parameter must be in {channels_last, channels_first}'

        if isinstance(output_shape, tuple):
            self.out_h = output_shape[0]
            self.out_w = output_shape[1]
        elif isinstance(output_shape, int):
            self.out_h = output_shape
            self.out_w = output_shape
        else:
            raise RuntimeError(f"""output_shape should be an Integer or a Tuple2""")

        self.data_format = data_format

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        # input_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
        input_shape = inputs.get_shape().as_list()

        if self.data_format == 'channels_last':
            h_idx, w_idx = 1, 2
        else: # can use else instead of elif due to assert in __init__
            h_idx, w_idx = 2, 3

        stride_h = input_shape[h_idx] // self.out_h
        stride_w = input_shape[w_idx] // self.out_w

        k_size_h = stride_h + input_shape[h_idx] % self.out_h
        k_size_w = stride_w + input_shape[w_idx] % self.out_w

        pool = tf.nn.avg_pool(
            inputs,
            ksize=[k_size_h, k_size_w],
            strides=[stride_h, stride_w],
            padding='VALID',
            data_format='NHWC' if self.data_format == 'channels_last' else 'NCHW')

        return pool
```

The problem is that, I'm using `inputs.get_shape().as_list()`
to recover int values and not a `Tensor(..., type=int)`. Indeed, the `tf.nn.avg_pool` accept a list of *Int* for both the `ksize` and the `strides` parameters...

Put it differently, I couldn't use `tf.shape(inputs)` because it returns a `Tensor(..., type=int)` and there is no way to recover a int from a Tensor beside by evaluating it...

The way I have implemented my function worked just fine, the problem is that, **Tensorflow** infers the size under the hood and save the size of all the tensors inside the `.pb` file when I save it.

Indeed, you can easily open a `.pb` file with any TextEditor (SublimeText) and see by ourself the expected `TensorShape`. In my case it was `TensorShape: **[null, 320, 320, 14]**

So, using `set_shape((None, None, None, 14))` instead of `set_shape((None, 320, 320, 14))` or `nothing` actually doesn't change the problem...

The problem is that **the average pooling layer does not accept a dynamic kernel size/strides**....

I then realizes that there is a tensorflow function for this actually `tfa.layers.AdaptiveAveragePooling2D`. So, I might just go with it and it will be fine, right?

Well not exactly, under the hood, this tensorflow function use other tf.function like `tf.split`. The problem with `tf.split` is that, if your dimension you want to split is of size X and you want to output a tensor of size Y. If X % Y != 0, when tf.split will throw an error... While Pytorch is much more robust and handle cases were X % Y != 0.

Put it differently, it means that, in order for me to use `tfa.layers.AdaptiveAveragePooling2D`, I need to be sure that the size of the tensor received by this function is divisible by the scalar I pass to the function.

For example, in my case,
The input image are of size: (320, 320, whatever), the input tensor received by `tfa.layers.AdaptiveAveragePooling2D` is: (40, 40, whatever).

So it means, that the spatial dimension of my tensor was divided by 8 during training. In order for it to work, I should choose a size that can divide 40. Let's say I choose **5**.

It means that during the prediction, my neural network will work if the input dimension that the `tfa.layers.AdaptiveAveragePooling2D` receives is also divisible by **5**. But we already know that my input image is 8x bigger then the tensor receives by `tfa.layers.AdaptiveAveragePooling2D`, so it means that, at prediction times, I can use whatever image  size as long as:

- H % (8*5) == 0 and W % (8 * 5) == 0
  Where `H` and `W` are respectively the height and the width of my input image.

To do that, we can just implement a simple function:
new_W = W + W % 40 (40 in this example...)
new_H = H + H % 40 (40 in this example...)

This function will stretch a bit the image but not to much so that it should be just fine.

Summing up:

- My AdaptivePooling uses static shape, but I cannot do otherwise since it uses `tf.nn.avg_pool` under the hood that doesn't accept dynamic shape
- `tfa.layers.AdaptiveAveragePooling2D` is a work around, but because it relies on `tf.split` that is not robust to inexact divide, it is not perfect either
- The basic solution is to use `tfa.layers.AdaptiveAveragePooling2D` and create a preprocessing function before calling the prediction so that the tensor will work just fine with `tf.split` constraint
- Finally, this is not a good solution either. Because, during training if I receive a tensor of size `(40, 40)` and want an **avg** output of size `(5, 5)`, it means that I basically average (8, 8) features to retrieve one features.
- The problem is that, if I do that during inference time on a bigger image, I will receive a bigger tensor. Let's say: `(100, 200)`. But since my output will always be `(5, 5)`, it means that I will, this time, average (20, 40) features to retrieve **one** feature...

Because of this difference between training and inference if I go with this way of doing, inferring on a bigger image might lead to inconsistent results
In my case, the way to go is to batch the images as I have explained in my first post...

Hope it will help some of you.